# Tidyverse filter by width of variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with an untidy dataset and want to filter out any object with an ID shorter than 6 digits (these rows contain errors).

I created a new column that calculates the number of characters for each ID, and then I filter for all objects with 6 or more digits, like so:

```
clean_df <- df %>%
 mutate(chars = nchar(id)) %>%
 filter(chars >= 6)
```

This is working just fine, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way.

Comment: Skip the `mutate()`? E.g. `clean_df <- df %>% filter(str_length(id) >= 6)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`str_length()`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_length.html) from the stringr package (part of the tidyverse):

```
library(tidyverse)

clean_df <- df %>%
 filter(str_length(id) >= 6)
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel silly that it's that simple.

Answer (score 0):

If `id`'s are numeric, just use `log10`

```
df %>%
  filter(log10(id)>=5)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can skip `mutate`

```
df %>%
  filter(nchar(id) >= 6)
```